# 3ds Max SDK linker errors after installing

Tags: c++, plugins, visual-studio-2019, blender, 3dsmax

I downloaded the [3ds Max SDK](https://aps.autodesk.com/developer/overview/3ds-max?_ga=2.192332399.456026891.1694554592-1673664290.1687321247#3dsmax-sdk) and opened the `maxsdk/samples/samples.sln` solution with Visual Studio 2019. I added the `maxsdk/lib` folder to the library directory and `maxsdk/include` file to the include directories, but I'm still getting unresolved external symbol errors and errors about files not being found.
The full build output is below.

The project has multiple solutions. I wasn't able to add the include and library paths using the base solution because the Properties window showed this

[image]

instead of the usual:

[image]

Anyway, when I try to change the properties for one the solutions in order to add the include and library paths, I don't think it's updating them for every solution in the project. When I add them all manually to each one I still seem to get unresolved external symbol errors.

Some of the individual solutions are able to build succesfully by themselves. But building the base solution always fails.

These errors are happening when using the sdk by itself with nothing else. I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio or using an older version but it doesn't seem to help.

Here is the build output. This is just a small fraction of the number of linker errors:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: NotificationSystem, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: PolyPaint, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: morpher (Modifiers\Morpher\morpher), Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: viewfile (Viewfile\viewfile), Configuration: Debug x64 ------
5>------ Build started: Project: ctrl, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
6>------ Build started: Project: auctrl, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
7>------ Build started: Project: block, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
8>------ Build started: Project: boolcntrl, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
9>------ Build started: Project: reactor, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
10>------ Build started: Project: jiggle, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
11>------ Build started: Project: wavectrl, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
12>------ Build started: Project: comsrvgup, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mnmath.lib'
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'geom.lib'
2>Done building project "PolyPaint.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
1>Done building project "NotificationSystem.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
13>------ Build started: Project: maxclient, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
14>------ Build started: Project: RenderingAPI, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>wm3_channel.cpp
3>wm3_core.cpp
4>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'bmm.lib'
4>Done building project "viewfile.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
15>------ Build started: Project: GeometryChecker, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
5>QtMsBuild: could not locate qt.targets, qt.props; project may not build correctly.
8>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'core.lib'
8>Done building project "boolcntrl.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
16>------ Build started: Project: plugman, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
6>   Creating library C:\Users\employee\Desktop\maxsdk\\obj\x64\Debug\auctrl\\auctrl.lib and object C:\Users\employee\Desktop\maxsdk\\obj\x64\Debug\auctrl\\auctrl.exp
7>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'core.lib'
7>Done building project "blockcontrol.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
17>------ Build started: Project: SaveVerification, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
11>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'geom.lib'
6>aupos.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl Tab<class FPInterface *>::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_G?$Tab@PEAVFPInterface@@@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)
12>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'bmm.lib'
12>Done building project "comsrvgup.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
10>   Creating library C:\Users\employee\Desktop\maxsdk\lib\x64\Debug\\spring.lib and object C:\Users\employee\Desktop\maxsdk\lib\x64\Debug\\spring.exp
6>aurot.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
6>auscale.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
6>auctrl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
6>aufloat.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
6>aup3dlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
6>aupoint3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
18>------ Build started: Project: CubeMap, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
11>Done building project "wavectrl.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
19>------ Build started: Project: hsutil, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
6>aupoint3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
6>aupos.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
6>aurot.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
6>auscale.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
6>auctrl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
6>aufloat.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
9>   Creating library C:\Users\employee\Desktop\maxsdk\\obj\x64\Debug\reactor\\reactor.lib and object C:\Users\employee\Desktop\maxsdk\\obj\x64\Debug\reactor\\reactor.exp
6>aup3base.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
6>aup3dlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
6>auctrl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl WStr::WStr(void)" (__imp_??0WStr@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: int __cdecl AudioBaseControl::FixupFilename(class WStr &,wchar_t const *)" (?FixupFilename@AudioBaseControl@@QEAAHAEAVWStr@@PEB_W@Z)
6>auctrl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl WStr::WStr(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_??0WStr@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z) referenced in function "public: int __cdecl AudioBaseControl::FixupFilename(class WStr &,wchar_t const *)" (?FixupFilename@AudioBaseControl@@QEAAHAEAVWStr@@PEB_W@Z)
6>aufloat.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl WStr::WStr(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_??0WStr@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z)
6>aup3dlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl WStr::WStr(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_??0WStr@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z)
10>PickModes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class BaseInterface * __cdecl InterfaceServer::GetInterface(class Interface_ID)" (?GetInterface@InterfaceServer@@UEAAPEAVBaseInterface@@VInterface_ID@@@Z)
10>SpringSys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class BaseInterface * __cdecl InterfaceServer::GetInterface(class Interface_ID)" (?GetInterface@InterfaceServer@@UEAAPEAVBaseInterface@@VInterface_ID@@@Z)
10>DlgProcs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class BaseInterface * __cdecl InterfaceServer::GetInterface(class Interface_ID)" (?GetInterface@InterfaceServer@@UEAAPEAVBaseInterface@@VInterface_ID@@@Z)
10>DllEntry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class BaseInterface * __cdecl InterfaceServer::GetInterface(class Interface_ID)" (?GetInterface@InterfaceServer@@UEAAPEAVBaseInterface@@VInterface_ID@@@Z)
5>layerctrl.cpp
16>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'maxutil.lib'
16>Done building project "plugman.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
14>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'maxscrpt.lib'
14>Done building project "RenderingAPI.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
20>------ Build started: Project: LightMap, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
13>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'comsrv.lib'
13>Done building project "maxclient.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
21>------ Build started: Project: mb_select, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
22>------ Build started: Project: Membrane, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
5>listctrl.cpp
10>jiggle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class BaseInterface * __cdecl InterfaceServer::GetInterface(class Interface_ID)" (?GetInterface@InterfaceServer@@UEAAPEAVBaseInterface@@VInterface_ID@@@Z)
10>jiggleFunctions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class BaseInterface * __cdecl InterfaceServer::GetInterface(class Interface_ID)" (?GetInterface@InterfaceServer@@UEAAPEAVBaseInterface@@VInterface_ID@@@Z)
10>PickModes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
10>SpringSys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
10>DlgProcs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
10>DllEntry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
10>jiggle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
10>jiggleFunctions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2MaxHeapOperators@@SAPEAX_K@Z)
10>NodeSearchEnumProc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
10>PickModes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
10>SpringSys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
10>SubAnimEnumProc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
10>DlgProcs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
10>DllEntry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
10>jiggle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
10>jiggleFunctions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl MaxHeapOperators::operator delete(void *)" (__imp_??3MaxHeapOperators@@SAXPEAX@Z)
10>PickModes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl assert1(int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?assert1@@YAHHPEB_W00@Z)
10>SpringSys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl assert1(int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?assert1@@YAHHPEB_W00@Z)
10>DlgProcs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl assert1(int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?assert1@@YAHHPEB_W00@Z)
10>DllEntry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl assert1(int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?assert1@@YAHHPEB_W00@Z)
10>jiggle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl assert1(int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?assert1@@YAHHPEB_W00@Z)
10>jiggleFunctions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl assert1(int,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (__imp_?assert1@@YAHHPEB_W00@Z)
10>PickModes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z)
10>SpringSys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z)
10>DlgProcs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z)
10>DllEntry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z)
10>jiggle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z)
10>jiggleFunctions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z)
10>PickModes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::~OutOfRangeException(void)" (__imp_??1OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@UEAA@XZ)
10>SpringSys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::~OutOfRangeException(void)" (__imp_??1OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@UEAA@XZ)
10>DlgProcs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::~OutOfRangeException(void)" (__imp_??1OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@UEAA@XZ)
10>DllEntry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::~OutOfRangeException(void)" (__imp_??1OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@UEAA@XZ)
10>jiggle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::~OutOfRangeException(void)" (__imp_??1OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@UEAA@XZ)
10>jiggleFunctions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::~OutOfRangeException(void)" (__imp_??1OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@UEAA@XZ)
10>PickModes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(class MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException const &)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@AEBV012@@Z)
10>SpringSys.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(class MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException const &)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@AEBV012@@Z)
10>DlgProcs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(class MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException const &)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@AEBV012@@Z)
10>DllEntry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(class MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException const &)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@AEBV012@@Z)
10>jiggle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(class MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException const &)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@AEBV012@@Z)
10>jiggleFunctions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException::OutOfRangeException(class MaxSDK::Util::OutOfRangeException const &)" (__imp_??0OutOfRangeException@Util@MaxSDK@@QEAA@AEBV012@@Z)
10>PickModes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl TBDelete(struct TabHdr * *,int,int,int)" (__imp_?TBDelete@@YAHPEAPEAUTabHdr@@HHH@Z)
10>DlgProcs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl TBDelete(struct TabHdr * *,int,int,int)" (__imp_?TBDelete@@YAHPEAPEAUTabHdr@@HHH@Z)
10>DllEntry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl TBDelete(struct TabHdr * *,int,int,int)" (__imp_?TBDelete@@YAHPEAPEAUTabHdr@@HHH@Z)
10>jiggle.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl TBDelete(struct TabHdr * *,int,int,int)" (__imp_?TBDelete@@YAHPEAPEAUTabHdr@@HHH@Z)
10>jiggleFunctions.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl TBDelete(struct TabHdr * *,int,int,int)" (__imp_?TBDelete@@YAHPEAPEAUTabHdr@@HHH@Z)
10>DlgProcs.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl WStr::WStr(void)" (__imp_??0WStr@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl Jiggle::UpdateNodeList(bool)" (?UpdateNodeList@Jiggle@@QEAAX_N@Z)
10>PickModes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl WStr::WStr(wchar_t const *)" (__imp_??0WStr@@QEAA@PEB_W@Z)
```